# What's the name of this co-op card-based game?

Tags: identify-this-game

You each are soldiers executing campaigns. Each turn you must play a card that contains a combination of some terrains and some symbols. If the board ever shows 3 of the same terrain or symbol, you lose the campaign. Instead of playing a card you can withdraw; if all players withdraw, you succeed in the campaign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [The Grizzled](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/171668/grizzled) or in its native language, Les Poilus.

An excerpt from [a description I found](http://nerdybutflirty.com/2015/08/07/10-new-games-im-most-excited-about-from-gen-con-2015/)

> Players take on the role of French soldiers in World War I. You can
>   choose your difficulty level, which means how many cards are in your
>   hand. On your turn, you can either play a card from your hand or
>   withdraw. There are two types of cards; ones with symbols on them
>   (night, rain, bullets, gas mask, etc) and ones with a lightning bolt
>   and text on them. If you play a symbol card, it goes into the river.
>   If you ever play a card that would cause you to have three of the same
>   symbol, you lose.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like The Grizzled from Cool Mini or Not, but you don't win by all players withdrawing. Instead you win by playing through all the cards of a draw deck and every player having no cards in their hand.

Comment: Right, you just succeed in the campaign; you don't win the whole game. Thanks!